# XML RPC add a date

Tags: python, web-services, odoo, xml-rpc, odoo-9

im trying to import salesorder from excel then insert them in sales order odoo

for now im trying to add the sales order then later i will add the order lines

```
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extras
import pyexcel_xls
import pyexcel as pe
from pyexcel_xls import get_data
from datetime import datetime
import xmlrpclib
import json

url = 'http://localhost:8070'
db = 'Docker'
username = 'admin'
password = 'odoo'
#data = get_data("salesorder.xls")
#print(json.dumps(data))
records = pe.get_records(file_name="salesorder.xls")
for record in records:
    print record['name']
    names = record['name']
    print record['location']
    print record['zip']
    print record['republic']
    dates = record['date']
    print dates
    print datetime.strptime(dates,'%d/%M/%Y')
    lastdat=datetime.strptime(dates,'%d/%M/%Y')


    common = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/common'.format(url))
    output = common.version()
    uid = common.authenticate(db, username, password, {})
    print output
    models = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/object'.format(url))
    models.execute_kw(db, uid, password,
        'res.partner', 'search',
        [[['is_company', '=', True], ['customer', '=', True]]])

    id = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'sales.order', 'create',             [{
        'name': "names",
        'validity_date':lastdat
        #'payment_term_id':"15"

    }])
    print id
```

the error im getting is on the 40th line the one with validity_date

Comment: Which one is the 40th line? What is the error ?

Comment: 'validity_date':lastdat
is the 40th line

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/.../somig/migrator.py", line 40, in <module>
    'validity_date':"2016-01-18"

Comment: Edit your question and add the full stack trace please so that we can help you

Comment: what do you mean by full stack trace the issue is on the date and the logs are too long to paste here

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Odoo's date format for using dates. It's the ISO 8601 international date format:  `YYYY-MM-DD`.